# Can't get stored procedure in entity framework to return values

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I tried creating a stored procedure in my DB and I tested it in Sql Server Management Studio (works fine), but when I call it from my MVC application using entity framework the results say - "Children could not be evaluated" when I expand on the results view.

Here is what I've tried so far.

```
public void ExecuteStoredProcedure()
    {
        //var gift = context.Gifts.SqlQuery("dbo.GetGiftsFromId @p0", 1);

        var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Gift>("dbo.GetGiftsFromId @p0", 1);

    }
```

Inside my stored procedure I have one line to execute.

```
SELECT * from dbo.Gifts where GiftId = @gift_id
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the call isn't returning anything? I see in other posts that some people are using modelbinder.Entity etc, etc in their code. Do I need to do this?

I'm using code first and here is my gift object

```
public class Gift
{
    // for a one-to-one relationship
    // great tutorial on code-first
    //http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

    public Gift()
    {
        Images = new List<GiftImage>();
    }

    public int GiftId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } 

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GiftCategory> Categories { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }

    public GiftStatus Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual GiftAddress GiftAddress { get; set; }

    public GiftAvailability Availability { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual GiftDescription Description { get; set; }

    public byte[] Thumbnail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<GiftImage> Images { get; set; }

    public ICollection<GiftReview> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I even wrote some ado.net code to get the sp to run and it works fine as well, I can return the data from the sp. EF is the problem here and I'm not sure if I'm missing some code somewhere. Note: I created the stored procedure in the DB directly. I didn't use any type of code first approach when I created the SP. Does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

I have to use.

```
results.ToList()
```

to get the results.

or something that takes the results and does something with it.